# Visual Studio App Center Android Build Project not finding Solution Files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying out the new Visual Studio App Center for a mobile app I am writing.

I have three solutions checked into VSTS Git. The first solution named App.sln is a master solution that has 2 solution folders, Apps and Services. The Apps folder has 3 projects App.csproj which is a .NET Standard 2.0 library containing the Xamarin Forms shared code. App.iOS.csproj is the Xamarin Forms iOS project. Finally, App.Droid.csproj is the Xamarin Forms Android project. The Services folder contains project files written in ASP.NET Core 2. The second solution is a solution named App.iOS.sln containing just the iOS and App library projects. The last is a solution named App.Droid.sln containing just the Android and App library projects.

In App Center I have 2 Apps configured per the instructions for Xamarin Forms apps. The first is an App configured as iOS Xamarin app. The second App is configured as Android Xamarin app.

I configured the analytics and crash reporting which works. I then configured the builds and this is where I have run into an issue. Specifically the Android build configuration project drop down only sees the App.Droid project. The iOS App build configuration project drop down sees all three solutions but only the App.iOS project. I selected the App.Droid and App.iOS projects. It seems to work. However I'm concerned that in the future things might break. I rather select the App.iOS and App.Droid solutions. That way I know that the correct projects are compiled and nothing not need is compiled. This is especially true since I am trying to stay within the free compile time budget until the MVP is done. Any ideas how to accomplish ensuring only the right projects are compiled?

Comment: You could ask question it in App Center's chat box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to App Center team (on Jan 30, 2018):

> Unfortunately we do not support the selection of sln's with Android
>   Xamarin, currently solution file is only supported for iOS.